# How to use Transactions in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, transactions

I write this code, but its not working, it gives this error

```
Call to a member function commit() on a non-object
```

Hear is my code

```
$datasource = $this->Arrear->getDataSource();               
$datasource->begin();
if($this->Customar->saveField("total_bake",$amount) && $this->Arrear->save()){

  $dataSource->commit();
  return  $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));

}else{

  $dataSource->rollback();
  $this->Session->setFlash('Data insert Failed','failure');

}
```

Comment: What's the question, what is your code for?

Comment: I think `$datasource = $this->Arrear->getDataSource();` returns you an array and not n object. But this may be different according to your cake-version. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in php(and hence in cakephp as well) are case-sensitive 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

you have in your first line

```
$datasource = $this->Arrear->getDataSource();
```

but you are committing like

```
$dataSource->commit();
```

you have the data source assigned to `$datasource`, but not to `$dataSource`. The last variable even is not defined, that is why it is showing that error. So, you have to be sure you are using exactly the same variable (with same capitalization) in all places.